# why is my route defined in a .ini file not working?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

In my `Bootstrap.php` I have the following code which defines a route:

```
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

    $router->addRoute('pageDetails', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('page-details/:uid/:title', array(
        'module'        => 'default',
        'controller'    => 'list',
        'action'        => 'detail',
    ), array(
        'uid'           => '\d+',
        'title'         => '(.*)?',
    )));
```

This works.

Then I tried to change the route setup to using a `.ini` file where the routes are defined. The `.ini` file looks like this:

```
[routes]
pageDetails.route = "page-details/:uid/:title"
pageDetails.default.module = "default"
pageDetails.default.controller = "list"
pageDetails.default.action = "detail"
pageDetails.reqs.uid = "\d+"
pageDetails.reqs.title = "(.*)?"
```

And I add the routes in `Bootstrap.php` via:

```
    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');

    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $router->addConfig(new Zend_Config_Ini($config['routes']['configPathname'], 'routes'));
```

Although the `.ini` version and the route defined in PHP code should do exactly the same, the `.ini` version does not work. There is no error message in the frontend, the links look allright but on clicking a link with this route I just get redirected to the start page.

What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the prefix 'routes' to them, as in the docs:

```
[routes]
routes.archive.route = "archive/:year/*"
routes.archive.defaults.controller = archive
routes.archive.defaults.action = show
routes.archive.defaults.year = 2000
routes.archive.reqs.year = "\d+"
```

Then try this:

```
$config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
$routes = new Zend_Config_Ini($config['routes']['configPathname'], 'routes')
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->addConfig($routes, 'routes');
```

Comment: Have you tried var_dump-ing the contents of $routes before adding them?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `{}|&~![()^"` characters in the key and you have to double-quote the string for the value if you use these characters.

So double quote:

```
pageDetails.reqs.title = ""(.*)?""
```

For more on this see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: Hm, sorry, that didnt seem to work, if I change that line in the ini file to make it look like you suggested, I get a Zend_Config_Exception with the message "syntax error, unexpected '(". Thanks for the hint though.